# How to have a user selected background image be persistent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to allow the user on my Django webapp to pick a background image and have it be persistent through all of the pages.

I have a way to let the user pick the image they want from the dashboard/home page from a list but as soon as they go to a different page or refresh it gets reset to the default css background image

This is the drop down list I have

```html
<select id="backgrounds">
    <option>Select a background</option>
    <option value="/static/images/traveling.jpg">Traveling</option>
    <option value="/static/images/Airplane.jpg">Airplane</option>
    <option value="/static/images/Beach.jpg">Beach</option>
    <option value="/static/images/Florence.jpg">Florence</option>
</select>
```

and this is the javascript I use to modify the css

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var body = $(document.body);
    $('#backgrounds').bind('change', function (event) {
        var bg = $(this).val();
        console.log(bg);
        if (bg == null || typeof bg === 'undefined' || $.trim(bg) === '')
            body.css('background-image', '');
        else
            body.css('background-image', "url('" + bg + "')");
    });
});
```

I can't figure out the best way to save the setting and keep it as the background-image on the different pages. Any help would be great and if any more information is necessary just let me know.

Comment: How long do you want it to be persistant?  If you only want it to be for that window, then you can use `sessionStorage`.  If you want it to be available for all windows you could use `localStorage`, and it would stick around through closing windows.  If you want it to persist through cache clearing, or across multiple browsers, then you will have to persist it server side.

Comment: localStorage would be fine for the time being, what's the best way to call on that to change the background image for every page that is opened?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax to store the user choice in the database or in the session.
Or, simpler, you can use localStorage or a cookie, but it is only saved on the current machine.